# How to setup an association between users and posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I have `has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy` in my user.rb and `belongs_to :user` in my post.rb, in my post migration i have `t.references :user` and `add_index :posts, :user_id` and then in my routes.rb i have:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts
end
```

How do I make it so that when i'm logged in as a user and I make a post the i can user `user.posts` and access those posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
respond_to :html

def index
  @posts = current_user.posts
end

def new
  @post = current_user.posts.new
end

def edit
  @post = current_user.posts.find params[:id]
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new params[:post]
  @post.save
  respond_with @post
end

def update
  @post = current_user.posts.find params[:id]
  @post.update_attributes params[:post]
  respond_with @post
end

def destroy
  @post = current_user.posts.find params[:id]
  @post.destroy
  respond_with @post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do:

```
def create
  if current_user.posts.create!(params[:post])
    # success
  else
    # validation errors
  end
end
```

The bottom line is, you want the post to have a foreign key called `user_id` that ties it to a user object.  By doing `current_user.posts...` it automatically associates the two.